# Regex- replace x{n} with x{n-2}

Tags: c#, regex

suppose I have this string:

```
var inputStr="AAAA AAAAAAAA AAA AAAAA";
```

**(The asumption here is that I don't know the size of each 'A...' sequence in the string.)**

I need a simple way to reduce 2 'A' characters from every "A..." sequence in that string

somthing like:

```
var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,...);
```

so that the result for this example will be: `"AA  AAAAAA  A  AAA"`)

thanks...

**UPDATE:**

thanks for all the replies,

I want to make this question more general.

example 2:

`var inputStr="bbbAAAAC1AAAAAAAA AAA AAAAArrr"`

and the result should be:

`"bbbAAC1AAAAAA A AAArrr"`

Comment: because every time you have to reduce 2 A in every occurance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "(A*)AA", "$1");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"(A*)A{2}(?!A)","$1");
```

Comment: Beat me to it (and it's funny, i kept trying it but forgot to use  a string literal and couldn't get a test working. ;-)

Comment: You don't need to capture anything.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes..It may be possible..but I can't think of any such solution..Could you post it as an answer or in comment

Comment: @Anirudh: Why not: `var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"(?<!A)AA", "");`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte nice solution..Though that would replace `n-2` times where n is the number of repeated A characters

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all the 'words' are `A`s, you can use this replace:

```
var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"AA\b","");
```

[regex101 demo for the regex replace](http://regex101.com/r/jU4dO3)

---

As per edit, a more general pattern would be:

```
var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"AA(?!A)","");
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wG0xA3)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a regex but it will work

```
String.Join(" ", inputStr.Split().Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.Length - 2)).ToArray());
```

Comment: did you mean `Substring`?

Comment: fwiw, `.Split` without a character automatically defaults to whitespace characters (those matching `Char.IsWhiteSpace`).

Comment: @BradChristie - Thanks for info, did not know it.

Comment: And there was an extra ToList() too

Comment: Also no need for `.toArray()` (`String.Join` has an overload of `IEnumerable<String>`). and you probably want to check if `x.Length > 2` before going ahead and truncating it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With regex although you dont really need it.

```
var result=Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"(?i)aa","AA");
```

The (?i) makes sure it checks a's of all cases.